# Why would one of my accounts not show up anywhere in my account listing?

Tags: support, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I have my English SE account show up on my list of SE accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102193/how-can-i-have-my-english-se-account-show-up-on-my-list-of-se-accounts)

It's not quite the same as [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86044/no-mathematics-account-listed-on-stackexchange-com) because even on the site of the missing account, all my other SE accounts are shown, but not that one. It's not some kind of joke to do with being an IT Security site, is it?

My account on IT Security is https://security.stackexchange.com/users/3677/bryan-agee.

[image: profile for Bryan Agee on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Comment: Are you saying that you have an account on IT Security, and that account is not showing in the account list of your other accounts?

Comment: Exactly. All of my account lists show the other accounts (including my user page on the IT Security site), but none show that account.

Comment: Interestingly enough, IT Security does show up in the appropriate position in the 'All Sites' list.

Comment: Also, my flair shows the IT site, but still no joy on the listing anywhere.

Comment: It's strange, because your IT Security icon shows up in your multi-account profile image, but not your profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty--so apparently clearing all associations and then re-linking them was the answer.