# How can I have my English SE account show up on my list of SE accounts?

Tags: support, linked-accounts

My account on [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) doesn't show up on my [SE account list](https://stackexchange.com/users/53f189b4-883a-47ed-8420-f3f36c68f1a5?tab=accounts) for more than a week despite having activity there.

I read [Why would one of my accounts not show up anywhere in my account listing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100530/why-would-one-of-my-accounts-not-show-up-anywhere-in-my-account-listing) but couldn't quite get what he exactly did to resolve his problem.

Is it some other kind of sync problem with my accounts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would one of my accounts not show up anywhere in my account listing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100530/why-would-one-of-my-accounts-not-show-up-anywhere-in-my-account-listing) (These questions should be merged; Jeremy's answer is far better than the accepted answer there.)

Comment: @CodyGray Indeed. We might as well close the earlier question as a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how you "clear associations", the solution from that question. Most issues like this can be fixed by clearing associations and then logging back into your accounts.

[image: Go to your profile. Under the default "info" section, select the "accounts" tab below your profile information. Scroll down to the bottom of that page and there is a button labeled "Clear all Stack Exchange account associations". Click it.]

Comment: Wow. Awesome mini-guide, thx :) I'll try that immediately ...

Comment: Worked! It even automagically reassociates all known accounts after clearing associations. Then takes some patience until the missing account finally shows up.